# How JVM use operating system when creation of thread?

Tags: java

Here i try to learn java thread clearlly.. On which process JVM create the thread.
Suppose if i create a thread in java then how JVM create this thread? To whom it will send to exicute?.. Which one is the base process for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the Java Virtual Machine Specification does not specify how threads are to be handled by a JVM. There is only a [high level description](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#33308). The Sun JVM itself made a change in this regard: Up to Java 1.1 it used so called [Green Threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads#Green_threads_in_the_Java_virtual_machine) that are managed by the JVM itself. Later it used native threads that the host operating system provides.

Comment: My question mainly on Java method(not more on native method). How JVM use Javastack, Frames,and Program Regiser for thread execution?

Comment: who will handle(os or Jvm) thread priority,intercommunication,synchronization? how jvm got the performance by in this design?...

Answer (score 6):

Most JVMs use standard OS calls to create native threads (eg, the Win32 `CreateThread` API, or POSIX `pthread_create`), and pass a native function within the JVM which proceeds to execute the Java code in the thread.

Comment: This might be true for a specific implementation. But it's not mandated.

Answer (score 3):

There is a separate JVM process for every running Java application. The threads that the application creates are created within that process.